# Cannot convert inherited generic?

Tags: c#, generics, .net-2.0, covariance

I am trying the following method, but it gives me a compiler error:

```
public class MyManager<T> : where T:MyEventArgs
{
    private Dictionary<EventHandler<T>, EventFilter<T>> m_cSubscriptions;

    public void Subscribe<K>(EventHandler<K> _cHandler, EventFilter<K> _cFilter)
    where K:T
    {
        try
        {
            // cannot convert EventHandler<K> to EventHandler<T>
            m_cSubscriptions.Add(_cHandler, _cFilter);
        }
        catch (ArgumentException)
        {
            m_cSubscriptions[_cHandler] = _cFilter;
        }
    }
}
```

Question: Why can't I convert the handler from K to T?

I am using a .net 2.0, because I am using Unity3D. Do I have to cast it myself? I have read about covariance and contravariance, but I couldn't make sense of this one.

Comment: You're trying to use covariance, which .Net 2 doesn't support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided to change the dictionary to a more common one by using `Delegate` and also defining a normal `EventFilter` class without generics. I hope that the casting will be correct, since I haven't tested this yet. I hope that it will work.

```
public class MyManager<T> : where T:MyEventArgs
{
    private Dictionary<Delegate, EventFilter> m_cSubscriptions;

    public void Subscribe<K>(EventHandler<K> _cHandler, EventFilter<K> _cFilter)
    where K:T
    {
        try
        {
            // cannot convert EventHandler<K> to EventHandler<T>
            m_cSubscriptions.Add(_cHandler, _cFilter);
        }
        catch (ArgumentException)
        {
            m_cSubscriptions[_cHandler] = _cFilter;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An `EventHandler<Derived>` is no `EventHandler<Base>`. Input parameters are contra-variant. So your code wouldn't work in C#4/.net 4 either.

You can work around this by creating a wrapper (This example only works with C#3, but similar code is possible with C#2):

```
(s,e) => handler(s, (K)e)
```

But you lose static type safety with this cast.

To convert delegates in the safe direction you can use my [`ConvertDelegate<T>`](https://github.com/CodesInChaos/ChaosUtil/blob/master/Chaos.Util/Conversion.cs) method.

Comment: But if I have already ascertained that `K:T`, I can safely cast it, correct?

Comment: @Marnix To safely cast you'd need to ascertain that `T:K` not `K:T`. As I said `in` parameters are contra-variant.

Comment: Ah true. The ConvertDelegate method won't work completely, since I also cannot convert `EventFilter<K>` to `EventFilter<T>`. And `EventFilter` is just a simple class. What is a better way to get these generic objects in the base list? I found something on interfaces?: http://www.fotia.co.uk/fotia/DN.01.CoVariantGenericList.aspx